# String reference in java

Tags: java, string, reference

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        test ob=new test();
        String st=new String("it is a string");

        System.out.println(ob);
    System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

in this code,ob is a reference of test class and st is a reference of string class.
while printing ob it shows  the reference but st prints the value i.e."it is a string".. why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you haven't overridden `toString()` in your `test` class so it uses the one from `Object` (the parent class of all objects in java) which is simply going to output the class name and hashcode.

Josh Bloch outlines this in "Effective Java":

http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf

(See: "Item 9: Always override toString")

Answer (score 6):

because string class overrides a method `toString` of `Object` class which is supposed to print whats passed to the constructor. But the test class doesnt do that.

Answer (score 4):

If you run `println` on an arbitrary object, it will print its string representation as produced by its [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method (defined in the `Object` class), which your class does not override. The default implementation prints the reference (or something to that effect).

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` class does not override `toString` but `String` does.  The  [`Object` implementation of `test`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) constructs a string from the class name and the `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling print on Java object merely *calls the toString() method* which is default inherited form the object class . Since String class has a *overridden behavior of toString()* to print the string value and your *test class don't have such an implementation* ,hence the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Java provides support for the representation of strings as literals, with compiler support for the automatic conversion of string literals into String objects; and the automatic conversion from any reference type (i.e. any subclass of class Object) into a printable string by using Object.toString method.

In your example, Here the Java compiler notes the signature of the method calls to the print statement is System.out.toString(String arg). Hence it knows that the arguments must be converted to a String.

Answer (score 1):

Every Java class extends Object class automatically even if you don't explicitly declare it and the `Object` class contains a `toStrong()` method which is used to get a `String` representing the instance of the `Object` class. The `toString()` method of the `Object` class is implemented to show the reference of object but that is not the actual reference (it is just a text containing information about reference).

However, this method may be overriden by its subclass and this is what what happens to a `String` class. The `toString()` method of the `String` class is overriden to represent the content that the `String` object holds.

Now, when you use `print` or `println` methods on an object, it calls the `toString()` method of the object and print those values.

In your case, `test` class has not overriden the `toString()` method so it prints out whatever value the `Object.toString()` gives.

Answer (score 1):

String is a special class in java where you can hold strings of data.

Every class by default extends java.lang.Object and you can override the toSring method to show what the data is in your class.

Since you have not overriden toString, it prints the reference.

On the other hand, String class provides an implementation of the toString(){
 returning this ; /// which prints the contents of the string. 
}

Answer (score 1):

You'll see much clear with an example:

```
class test {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "test={no attributes to print}";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test ob = new test();
        String st = new String("it is a string");

        System.out.println(ob);
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

and result in:

```
test={no attributes to print}
it is a string

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```